# Blazor SSR page is not loading JS properly after being switched by InteractiveServer

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor, .net-8.0

I'm using .NET 8 Blazor for this project.
I have 2 razor pages there.

Home.razor which is being rendered as SSR.
There's pure JS navigation implemented to it, because it can't use C#. When button is clicked it redirects user to "/booking".

```
$('#booking-btn').on('click', function () {
    window.location.href = '/booking';
});
```

Booking.razor which is being rendered as InteractiveServer. There's C# navigation implemented to it. When button is clicked NavigationManager redirects user to "/".

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

private void ReturnToHome()
{
    NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
}
```

The problem is when user loads the website and clicks the button for the first time (at home page) it works and redirects to booking. Then, when he clicks the button at the booking page it works every time and redirects to home page. But when the user is redirected to the home page, the home page button stops working.

So i'm assuming that i messed up with the rendering and the JS do not want to load properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use forceLoad on navigationmanager will make the ssr javascript load again.

```
    private void ReturnToHome()
    {    
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/", forceLoad: true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by enhance navigation of blazor static server rendering. You need to implement JS Initializer that will provide "hook" to run page specific javascript.

Refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/static-server-rendering?view=aspnetcore-8.0) for more detail.